# Match case invalid syntax, but no syntax error without match code

Tags: python, syntax, youtube, switch-statement, match

I'm running python 3.9.7 and am making a youtube video info viewer / downloader. Without the match statement the code runs fine and doesn't have any errors with concern to missing brackets. An interesting thing is that [Atom](https://atom.io) doesn't show match with any colour in my code, however it seems not to do that in a blank file with only the match anyway.

```py
# A youtube info and downloader
import getpass

from pytube import YouTube
from pathlib import Path

username = getpass.getuser()
downloads_path = str(Path.home() / "Downloads")

# Create video object
link = input("Enter video link (Don't forget https://): ")
video_object = YouTube(link)

# Print info
print(f"Title:  {video_object.title}")
print(f"Length: {round(video_object.length / 60, 2)} minutes")
print(f"Views:  {round(video_object.views / 1000000, 2)} million")
print(f"Author: {video_object.author}")

# Download
print("Download: (b)est | (w)orst | (a)udio | (e)xit")
download_choice = input(f"{username} $ ")

match download_choice:
    case: "b":
        video_object.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(downloads_path)

    case: "w":
        video_object.streams.get_worst_resolution().download(downloads_path)

    case: "a":
        video_object.streams.get_audio_only().download(downloads_path)
```

Edit:
I'm running it in the terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to install Python 3.10 from python.org because matching was only added in Python 3.10.

Comment: Relevant docs: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html

Answer (score 1):

When getting invalid syntax error on match statement, **check that you have at least python 3.10 installed** as this is the version it was released.

You can check your current version

cmd

```
python -V
```

python

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

**Install the latest version of python (Windows)**
Download installer: https://www.python.org/downloads/

or

Chocolatey update
cmd install chocolatey if not already (paste to admin shell)

```
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
```

Update python version (3.x)

```
choco upgrade python3 --pre
```

Sources:
https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/how-to-update-python/
https://www.python.org/downloads/
https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#install-with-cmd.exe